# TMPDIR does not change build directory for pip install

Tags: python-3.x, pip

I'm running pip various versions of pip over 20.X.  For some reason, the --build option was removed from these later versions for install.  I want to change the location of the pip builds because /tmp is occasionally cleaned up mid-install by a Jenkins plugin that cleans /tmp.  Please don't tell me to disable the plugin :)

It's documented that setting TMPDIR environment variable will allow me to set the build directory.  When I run in verbose mode, I still see /tmp being used for req-tracker and unpack folders.

What am I doing wrong? How can I change the build directory for pip install?

Setup of virtualenv

```
VENV=$(mktemp -d venv.XXXXXXX)
python -m venv $VENV
. $VENV/bin/activate
export TMPDIR=$VENV/build
python -m pip install --verbose -r requirements.txt
```

I stopped the job and I see folders newly created in /tmp

```
$ lt /tmp/
total 116
drwx------ 47 dom.larosa dom.larosa  4096 Feb 17 06:54 pip-build-sx9op49f
drwx------  2 dom.larosa dom.larosa  4096 Feb 17 06:54 pip-3at9dsy4-record
```

I see nothing in TMPDIR which is where I would like the temporary build directories to be

```
$ lt $VENV/build
ls: cannot access 'venv.WFWImFB/build': No such file or directory
```